# $f_n$ are continuously differentiable , then so is the uniform limit function $f$. prove or disprove

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

Let $f_n$ and $f$ be continuous functions on an interval [a , b] and assume that $f_n$ tends to f uniformly on [a , b].. If $f_n$ are continuously differentiable , then so is the limit function $f$.

Can anyone help me out to prove or disprove this. I am really clueless..

Comment: Consider $[a,b]=[-1,1]$ and $f_n(t)=\sqrt{t^2+\frac1n}$.

Comment: Disproof: $$f_N(t)=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\sin(n^3 x)}{n^2}$$

Comment: How the limit function is not continuously differentiable?  Can U plz explain?@JackD'Aurizio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$f_n(x) = \sqrt{\frac1{n} + x^2}$$

defined on $[-1,1]$ e.g. then $f_n(x) \rightarrow |x|$ uniformly.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the fact that any continous function on $[a,b]$ [can be uniformly approximated by polynomials thanks to Weierstrass' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem). And polynomials are differentiable, $C^1$, $C^ \infty$ and even analytic.

Now also consider the fact that there are "many" continuous functions on $[a,b]$ that are not everywhere differentiable. Some are even [nowhere differentiable, thanks to another result of Weierstrass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function).